# JPA create query only once

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc, jpa-2.0

Firstly, sorry if I am asking the obvious or if the question it is fundamentally dumb in nature.

More an academic question need to know if I can create a JPA query (named or whatever), that spans across or is independent of an `EntityManager` . Basically,  *Prepare once run always*. I do understand that we can only get a Query instance from the enitity manager objects's `createXXXQuery` methods, but still, is there another way?

This is what is am trying to do,

```
public class MyRepo {
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em;

 private Query aQueryIntentedtoBePreparedOnlyOnce;

 @PostConstruct
 public void prepareMyQuery(){
  aQueryIntentedtoBePreparedOnlyOnce = em.createQuery("...."); // Query with positional params
   }

  public void executeMyQuery(){
   aQueryIntentedtoBePreparedOnlyOnce.getResultList();
  }
 }
```

This executes perfectly the first time. But, the second time it says "Entity Manager Closed." I understand this is cause the EM is Transaction scoped.

This EM is container managed(JTA - Spring), so I can't extend it across transactions. And, using Session beans is not an option. So, is there a way to create this query only once?

PS : Where do Named queries and query caching come here? with Named queries I still seem to do `createNamedQuery` every time. And what is query cache plan are  there any good docs for it?

One other question, why are queries only created on the EM or on a Connection(JDBC)? Don't I just need to know which DB I'm talking to in-order to prepare a query? It is so that one can never execute one without a proper connection?

Comment: You cannot. With plain hibernate you could use a `DetachedCriteria` but that in the end still needs to become a `Criteria` instance for execution and for that you still need a `Session` (or in JPA terms an `EntityManager`). But why would you want to do this? You won't gain any/much performance (it will only use more memory) and the actual query is (if configured) cached by your JDBC driver.

Comment: @M. Deinum I dont have to do this, just wondering if I was missing something. And why would it consume more memory? cause the query is a member of my repo Object? Doesn't the SQL change with the parameters what use is a JDBC drive cached SQL?

Comment: No. As the `PreparedStatement` is cached not the query with the bound parameters. You have more objects in memory hence more memory. Now you have a very short lived object, which is pretty fast removed from memory.

Comment: I'd expect a JPA provider to cache the compilation of JPQL into SQL, and so that would be reused in a different EntityManager (DataNucleus does it this way). Consequently there is no recompilation of JPQL seen. The only thing seen is execution of the same SQL at a later point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Query object is tied to a specific EntityManager and cannot be reused in another, just as each EntityManager is tied to one JDBC connection.

The named queries are a way to cache the compiled queries and useful metadata about them. Normally when you use `em.createQuery` it parses it every time. It may keep some information about it in a cache, because it's very likely to encounter the same query again, but that's not required.

Queries are created by calling `createStatement` (returning a `Statement`), `prepareStatement` (returning a `PreparedStatement` which inherits the previous one) or `prepareCall` (returning a `CallableStatement` which inherits the previous two) on the JDBC connection. Those Statement objects have no interface to switch to another connection. Depending on the driver, they may be cached within the Java application or on the server. A Statement can be reused as many times as you want on the same connection, but not on others.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. So, I cant prevent compiling the JPQL, but, can gain performance through the use of Named queries?

Comment: Half-Yes. Named queries will slightly improve performance, but not greatly. The JPA provider will likely store them compiled. You just have to create them by name. Normally though annotations.